# I can't get my result number to accumulate up

Tags: python

I want to print out Result 1: heads, result 2: tails etc but I can only get it to print result 1 all the way down. How do i get it to accumulate?

```
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0
toss = heads + tails

count = int(input("How many coin tosses would you like to simulate?"))
max_result,curr_result = 0,0
max_head_streak,max_tail_streak,curr_head_streak,curr_tail_streak = 0,0,0,0

while heads + tails < count:
    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        heads = heads + 1
        curr_head_streak += 1
        curr_tail_streak = 0
        print("Result",curr_result + 1,": Heads")
    else:
        tails = tails + 1
        curr_tail_streak += 1
        curr_head_streak = 0
        print("Result",curr_result + 1,": Tails")
        
    max_head_streak = max(max_head_streak,curr_head_streak)
    max_tail_streak = max(max_tail_streak,curr_tail_streak)
    
print("The total amount of heads: ",heads)
print("the best streak of heads: ",max_head_streak)
print("The total amount of tails: ",tails)
print("The best streak of tails: ",max_tail_streak)
```

The rest of the program works just as I want it to.

Comment: store the result in a string or list

Comment: You have kept the curr_result = 0, at the beginning. You have to increment that value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize your variable `curr_result` above your while loop on line 8 to be equal to `0`.

You then refer to this variable on lines 17 and 22 where you write:

```
print("Result",curr_result + 1,": Heads")
```

```
print("Result",curr_result + 1,": Tails")
```

Since you've initialized `curr_result` to be equal to `0`, on the first iteration, this will print either

```
Result1: Heads
```

or

```
Result1: Tails
```

However, when the program iterates again, `curr_result` is still equal to 0, since you haven't actually updated the variable, you've just printed the variable plus one.

To fix this, I'd suggest including the following line below the if/else statement but still within the while loop:

`curr_result += 1`

Answer (score 4):

You don't update you `curr_result` variable

Suggested solution:

```py
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0
toss = heads + tails

count = int(input("How many coin tosses would you like to simulate?"))
max_result,curr_result = 0,0
max_head_streak,max_tail_streak,curr_head_streak,curr_tail_streak = 0,0,0,0

while heads + tails < count:
    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    curr_result += 1
    if coin == 1:
        heads = heads + 1
        curr_head_streak += 1
        curr_tail_streak = 0
        print("Result",curr_result,": Heads")
    else:
        tails = tails + 1
        curr_tail_streak += 1
        curr_head_streak = 0
        print("Result",curr_result,": Tails")
        
    max_head_streak = max(max_head_streak,curr_head_streak)
    max_tail_streak = max(max_tail_streak,curr_tail_streak)
    
print("The total amount of heads: ",heads)
print("the best streak of heads: ",max_head_streak)
print("The total amount of tails: ",tails)
print("The best streak of tails: ",max_tail_streak)
```

Answer (score 1):

Others seem to have answered already why your code isn't working, so here is just another way to solve your problem using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

count = int(input("How many coin tosses would you like to simulate? "))

tally = defaultdict(int)
results = []
sides = ["tails", "heads"]
for i in range(count):
    side = random.choice(sides)
    tally[side] += 1
    results.append(side)

# Iterates over results, creating groups by repeated entries.
groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(results)]

# filters the given list of groups for the different results,
# and gives it to the max function
heads_streak = max([len(l) for l in groups if "heads" in l])
tails_streak = max([len(l) for l in groups if "tails" in l])

print(f"The total amount of heads: {tally['heads']}")
print(f"the best streak of heads: {heads_streak}")
print(f"The total amount of tails: {tally['tails']}")
print(f"the best streak of tails: {tails_streak}")
print(results)
```

Output:

```
How many coin tosses would you like to simulate? 10
The total amount of heads: 5
the best streak of heads: 2
The total amount of tails: 5
the best streak of tails: 2
['tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads']
```

---

EDIT: The above code works on the assumption that there will always be values of both types in `groups`. We can change that behavior by using the ["walrus operator" (new in 3.8)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```
heads_streak = max(x if (x := [len(l) for l in groups if "heads" in l]) else [0])
tails_streak = max(x if (x := [len(l) for l in groups if "tails" in l]) else [0])
```

Not the prettiest piece of code I've written, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't increment the value of curr_result. Maybe you wanted to use a for loop instead? This achieves the same thing as your while loop:

```py
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0
toss = heads + tails

count = int(input("How many coin tosses would you like to simulate?"))
max_result = 0
max_head_streak,max_tail_streak,curr_head_streak,curr_tail_streak = 0,0,0,0

for curr_result in range(count):
    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        heads = heads + 1
        curr_head_streak += 1
        curr_tail_streak = 0
        print("Result", curr_result + 1,": Heads")
    else:
        tails = tails + 1
        curr_tail_streak += 1
        curr_head_streak = 0
        print("Result", curr_result + 1,": Tails")

    max_head_streak = max(max_head_streak,curr_head_streak)
    max_tail_streak = max(max_tail_streak,curr_tail_streak)

print("The total amount of heads: ",heads)
print("the best streak of heads: ",max_head_streak)
print("The total amount of tails: ",tails)
print("The best streak of tails: ",max_tail_streak)
```